# chrome file system inspection - reload on change

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, livereload

is there an extension for loading an entire page on change in file system in entire folder. I am right now using Tincr but it doesn't allow me watch the entire folder.

there is an auto reload for firefox which watches folder and filters on extension convieniently

Answer (score 2):

Not really the answer you want but:

1. have you considered writing a script / program that monitors the entire folder and (when a change is detected) "touch"es the file Tincr monitors? that should be simple - and would result in the effect you need.
2. keep in mind that tincr uses the NPAPI which (according to Google) would no longer be allowed on Chrome come Jan 1st, 2015.

Comment: using gulp script to watch for files is simple..but can that be run in as an chrome extension to reload the tab

Comment: I was aiming at something else: a program that runs on your machine (not in the browser) that monitors the files in your folder for changes. Not an extension, but something that would take advantage of tincr's behavior.

Comment: that is exactly what gulp does..and socket program to monitor the change and issue reload...sound simple..if some body can make it